# How should I delete particular row from table by deselecting checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I have to delete entry from database on deselecting selected checkbox from webpage in php..

Comment: On Click on this  checkbox make an Ajax call to a php page to delete values from db('s).

Comment: use ajax deselcting of your checkbox

Comment: What did you tried yet ?

Comment: So what.? Go and delete the item.? Do face a problem there.?

Comment: Please can you give me the link for make an Ajax call to a php page to delete values from db('s) by deselecting checkbox

Comment: @Yogeshk try to see the answer, maybe can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:
There are many ways to do it. This is an way to do it.

I have done this by ajax. On change in your check box i have sent a ajax request to delete.php file and sent an id as parameter. i have set id withinh checkbox id and i have split it and get id. After that i have sent it as id.

**JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[id^='chk-']").on("change",function(){
        if(!this.checked){
            var arrid= (this.id).split('-');
            id = arrid[1];

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "/delete.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {"id" : id}
        });
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            //this.hide();
        });
        }
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" checked id="chk-1"> good<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car"  checked id="chk-2"> great
```

In your php file you will have this id by $_REQUEST['id'] and perform delete operation ib the database

**delete.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $sql = "delete from your table where id= $id limit 1";
//run this query

}
```

**jquery ajax ref:**

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm

**Php ref:**

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_delete_php.htm